# How can build postgresql with LOCK_DEBUG enabled?

Tags: postgresql

I have been strugglling to build posqlgresql 9.1 with trace_locks on so I can check the memory addresses used by the locks, but after a couple of days effort, I still haven't made any progress.

to compile:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql --enable-depend --enable-cassert --enable-debug
make
make install
```

According to postgresql documentation, LOCK_DEBUG should be set at compile time,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql --enable-depend --enable-cassert --enable-debug LOCK_DEBUG='on'
```

but it doesn't seem like working.
Please help! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to get `-DLOCK_DEBUG` into the compiler flags, try it like this:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql \
    --enable-depend --enable-cassert \
    --enable-debug \
    CPPFLAGS='-DLOCK_DEBUG'
```

I added the backslashes to make it easier to read, you can use this if you want it all in one line:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql --enable-depend --enable-cassert --enable-debug CPPFLAGS='-DLOCK_DEBUG'
```

You can find examples of similar things in [the installation documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/install-procedure.html), just search for "CFLAGS":

> You can specify environment variables on the configure command line, for example:
>
> ```
> ./configure CC=/opt/bin/gcc CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe'
> ```

Comment: @Peter: Thanks (and thanks for your work on two of my favorite projects ever). Presumably there's no value for the macro too, just an existence check.

Comment: @jess: Thanks so much for the quick reply!!! I included CPPFLAGS='-DLOCK_DEBUG' in the build. but I still don't see anything changed in the postgresql.conf file. So I added #trace_locks = true in the postgresql.conf and restarted the server.  I don't see the lock trace I want to get from lock.c in my log file when I insert row into a table (I changed the min logging level to log and everything else logs fine except log trace). Any ideas??? Thanks !!!

Comment: @Peter is the expert, hopefully he will have some advice.

Comment: @jess: `#trace_locks = true` means it's commented out, so fix that.